# Is there a way to send a verification email to a custom email id (say to an admin) instead of the user's email id using Firebase Auth?

Tags: firebase, authentication, flutter, email-validation

I am using flutter for this project. My goal is to send a verification email to the admin once the user has registered his/her account. The profile will be registered once the admin verifies it through email.

I am aware that we can send a verification email to the user itself to verify the email id by using Firebase Auth. I was wondering whether there is a way to change the reciever's address from the user to an admin's email id(custom email id). If no then is there any other way to perform this task ?

Thank you in advance for the help.

I am using Cloud Firestore as a database service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-functions) to know when a user was created or deleted.

But if you want to get an email only after the email was confirmed, then you would have to do it inside your app, triggering some logic that sends you a message from inside your app once you detect the email is verified.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the destination of the verification email.  It will always go to the email address that was used at the time of signup.

If your goal is to prevent the user from doing anything with some backend resource until after an admin authorizes them, what you can do is use custom claims to add a flag to the account that can be checked by security rules or your backend endpoint.  The presence of that flag can be used to tell if an admin has authorized them.  You will have to build out some amount of backend infrastructure to make all that work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember there are Firebase Authentication triggers that you can use to listen to new user creations. You need to setup a Firebase function that listens for user creation events.

```
functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  //send email to admin
}
```

Another step that you can take is to disable the newly created account and also send email to the user as well telling him that his account is disabled until admin approves it. You can achieve this using Firebase Admin SDK. And maybe create another cloud function that admin activates to enable the account back. So maybe something like this:

```
functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // disable this account
  // send user email to let him know that his account is disabled until approval
  // send email to admin to ask for his approval for the account
}

() {// another cloud function that enables the user account called by admin}
```

This may not be the best solution but it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ........... I digged some info regarding that approach and I have a query ...... Now I want to create a custom email template which will have  a button in it (like to confirm the registration) and once pressed, the profile will be registered ........So is there any way to add a button in our email ?

Comment: yes you can do it. You can use `nodemailer` in your cloud function to send an email and a custom body. Let me know if it worked for you.